# Como e onde excluo minha conta do stackoverflow?

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Como excluo minha conta do site? Não quero mais participar da comunidade.

Comment: Bem, daqui a pouco os moderadores vão ver sua pergunta e dar um jeito nisso. Não lembro os detalhes, mas sei que há uma etapa onde você tem que editar o conteúdo do seu perfil e colocar lá uma mensagem do tipo "favor me excluir", é algo que serve para confirmar o seu pedido.